# Memory leak in iOS webview when I add touch event

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, dom-events, touch-event

I'm making hybrid app and I use iframe in WebView.

My app is dead When I attach touch event (like `ontouchstart`) to div by use `addEventListener.

Many times, if I attach event except touch event (like `onclick`) app is not dead.

Is there memory leak in Javascript touchevent?

I can't find any solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Please rephrase your question and use proper English.

Comment: Show us the code where you add the touch event and where you handle the touch event.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is bugging somewhere between adding / removing javascript events, but I don't know why the specific "touch" events are causing problem. Maybe testing the same resources in Safari, Chrome or android browser would be helpful.